# Angular Proxy to .net Core backend works every other time

Tags: angular, .net-core, proxy

Running into some weird stuff.. Trying to hit my api from my angular app. Since We need to use windows authentication we need to setup a proxy.conf for angular so it can pass credentials correctly.
Here is my proxy.conf.js:

```js
    const agent = require('agentkeepalive');

    module.exports = {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:44366',
            secure: false,
            agent: new agent({
                maxSockets: 100,
                keepAlive: true,
                maxFreeSockets: 10,
                keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                timeout: 6000000,
                keepAliveTimeout: 90000,
            }),
            onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
                let key = 'www-authenticate';
                proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
            },
        },
    };
```

Getting these errors every other request:
[image]

Without fail my first request succeeds but the following request fails with 502 every time.
[image]

[image]

Has anyone ever seen something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

```
const { env } = require('process');
const HttpsAgent = require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent;

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:32101';

  const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
      context: ["/api"],
      target: target,
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true,
      agent: new HttpsAgent({
        maxSockets: 100,
        keepAlive: true,
        maxFreeSockets: 10,
        keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
        timeout: 6000000,
        freeSocketTimeout: 90000
      }),
      onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
        const key = "www-authenticate";
        proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
          proxyRes.headers[key].split(",");
      }
    }
  ]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

try this but im not confident with your port number mentioned above - you have to set proxy configuration for https and routes of web api, this code is example from my proxy.conf.js for new Visual Studio Template

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).